# Immense slow / hanging query when searching Magento 2

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, performance

I am sorry that I can't supply more information. We have tried Mirasvit Ultimate Search but at one point it fills up and crashes, ruining the website layout. (I am in contact with Mirasvit and will give access to development environment. In the mean time, I need this to perform better and not cause the website to crash.)

We now use the standard search again but this also piles up somehow with the follow queries:

```
INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5a5de009b26075_57197513` 
SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`,
       MAX(score) AS `relevance`
FROM (
    SELECT
        `search_index`.`entity_id`,
        (((0) + (0)) * 1 + SUM((
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE ' vt keramieke vervangschijf voor rvs diffusor aqv7757 '
                 THEN 5
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '% vt %'
                 THEN 3
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '% keramieke %'
                 THEN 3
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '% vervangschijf %'
                 THEN 3
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '% voor %'
                 THEN 3
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '% rvs %'
                 THEN 3
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '% diffusor %'
                 THEN 3
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '% aqv7757 %'
                 THEN 3
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '%vt%'
                 THEN 2
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '%keramieke%'
                 THEN 2
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '%vervangschijf%'
                 THEN 2
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '%voor%'
                 THEN 2
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '%rvs%'
                 THEN 2
                 ELSE 0
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN `data_inde[...]
```

And these queries keep piling up as long as customers search for them. So if a customer is impatient (which they are) they'll press enter numerous times.

Is there any way we can handle these queries more efficiently, or is there any advice regarding the searching situation on Magento 2? I did read a lot that the search is not very efficient.

If anyone has advice or any helpful URL's that can point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Dekcolnu so could you please share your findings here? What was causing slow search? How did you overcome that?

Comment: @GauravPandey we've never really gotten a permanent solution sadly. Performance seemed a bit better after updating/upgrading Magento and using Mirasvit Ultimate Search module.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I also changed the extension to elastic search one. Mirasvit support told that these queries are Magento's default queries and are unrelated to their extension. So looks like one has to live with these queries.

Comment: @GauravPandey Yes, and whole problem for high load seems to be that opening a product in front-end are acting exactly as doing a search with the search bar in default Magento 2, to my opinion this seems to be a weird query, but I guess they have their reasons for it. 

Did changing extension to Elastic Search improve anything for you, or same load?

Comment: Yes there were other full text queries which were offloaded from database once we integrated elasticsearch. Which resulted in decreased load on db and better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a real search engine instead of the MySQL one.
ElastcSuite should run smoothly : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Comment: Some other suggestion 

Algolia
Adobe Commerce Live Search